# Superfish menu arrow drop-down indicator for non-link item

Tags: jquery, menu, joomla-extensions, superfish

I am using Superfish in Joomla for my menu and I want to add a "text separator" menu item as the parent for list of drop-down items, so the separator item is not a link, but when hovered it shows the children items i.e.:

```
<ul>
<li><span class="separator">About</span>
<ul>
<li><a>Mission</a></li>
<li><a>Staff</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

However, when I do this Superfish does not add the arrow image indicating that there are child items to the Separator.

The html that is output for a parent item that is a regular link is:

```
<li class="item-470 deeper parent">
<a class="sf-with-ul" href="/joomla/index.php/en/about">
About
<span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span>
</a>
<ul class="nav-child unstyled small" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
<li class="item-471">
<a href="/joomla/index.php/en/about/our-values">Our Values</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

The html that is output for the parent item that is a text separator is:

```
<li class="item-472 divider deeper parent">
<span class="separator">Projects</span>
<ul class="nav-child unstyled small" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
<li class="item-614">
<a href="/joomla/index.php/en/projects/about-our-projects">About Our Projects</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

What is missing is the `<span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span>`. I thought that maybe I could force it to apply to the parent text separator as well as the parent link menu item by modifying the default_separator.php file in the module's tmpl folder, but so far no luck.